# Java - draw a triangle

Tags: java, random, geometry, draw

Hey I know that it is simple to draw oval/rectangle and fill it using

```
g.fillOval(30, 40, 20, 20);
```

but how to draw a triangle? It would be the best if it would have random coordinates.

Comment: not very clear.  What library is this?  Where is method fillOval?  What type is g?

Comment: with `drawpolygon(int[] x, int[] y, int numberOfPoints)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears the poster hasn't tried anything.

Comment: Hint: A triangle is a polygon with 3 edges/vertices.

Comment: @La-comadreja It's not very clear, but it's a virtual certainty we're dealing with our old friend `Graphics g`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two basics ways you can achieve this, based on your needs.

You could use [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) or you could make use the [2D Graphics Shape API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html)

Which you might choose comes down to your requirements.  `Polygon` requires you to know, in advance the position of the points within 3D space, where the `Shape` API gives you more freedom to define the shape without caring about the position in advance.

This makes the `Shape` API more flexible, in that you can define the shape once and simply translate the `Graphics` context as needed and repaint it.

For example...

[image: Triangle]

Red is a `Polygon`, green is a `Shape`, which is translated into position...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TriangleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TriangleTest();
    }

    public TriangleTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private TriangleShape triangleShape;
        private Polygon poly;

        public TestPane() {
            triangleShape = new TriangleShape(
                    new Point2D.Double(50, 0),
                    new Point2D.Double(100, 100),
                    new Point2D.Double(0, 100)
            );

            poly = new Polygon(
                    new int[]{50, 100, 0},
                    new int[]{0, 100, 100},
                    3);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(poly);

            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.translate(50, 100);
            g2d.fill(triangleShape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class TriangleShape extends Path2D.Double {

        public TriangleShape(Point2D... points) {
            moveTo(points[0].getX(), points[0].getY());
            lineTo(points[1].getX(), points[1].getY());
            lineTo(points[2].getX(), points[2].getY());
            closePath();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for the `closePath()` method. I'm going to use that one as well.

Answer (score 6):

Using the legacy [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class, this would be done by using the legacy method
[`drawPolygon(int[] x, int[] y, int pointCount)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29).

The newer class [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) supports a much nicer implementation using [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html)s.  You will need either the [`draw(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) or [`fill(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) method. Given the fact that almost everywhere in Java a `Graphics` object is actually a `Graphics2D` object, you can cast it so, that is the way to go, IMHO.

```
Graphics g = ...;
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
Path2D.Double triangle = new Path2D.Double();
triangle.moveTo(x1, y1);
triangle.pathTo(x2, y2);
triangle.pathTo(x3, y3);
triangle.closePath();
g2d.fill(triangle);
```

Comment: +1 for both `Polygon` and `Path`