# Draw Triangles with help of Polygon in java

Tags: java, geometry, awt, polygon

I want to draw 3 triangles like this 
I am trying but not getting what i want. any one can help

Here is my code in java. 
I dont know hot to handle the coordinates. and did not find related help form internet,

Basically i need the coordinates which i have to put. 
Thanks.

```
private Polygon triangle;
public TrianglePanel(){
        triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(400, 500);           
        triangle.addPoint(500, 500);
        triangle.addPoint(450, 400);
}
```

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564837/java-draw-a-triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Code

```
        triangle1 = new Polygon();
        triangle1.addPoint(400, 550);        //left   
        triangle1.addPoint(600, 550); //right
        triangle1.addPoint(500, 350); //top
        triangle2 = new Polygon();
        triangle2.addPoint(600, 550);  // left
        triangle2.addPoint(700, 350); //top
        triangle2.addPoint(800, 550);  //right
        triangle3 = new Polygon();
        triangle3.addPoint(500, 350); //left
        triangle3.addPoint(700, 350); //right
        triangle3.addPoint(600, 150); //
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the below Values.

```
        Polygon triangle1 = new Polygon();
        triangle1.addPoint(100, 500); // first
        triangle1.addPoint(600, 500);//last
        triangle1.addPoint(350, 300);//middel

        Polygon triangle2 = new Polygon();
        triangle2.addPoint(350, 500); // first
        triangle2.addPoint(475, 400);//last
        triangle2.addPoint(225, 400);//middel
```