# Create the square, rectangle, triangle of java in jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics, geometry, custom-painting

I have a problem with Java As I understood not come Draw Geometric figures in Java, the code and the Following you can help me?

This is the code:

```
public class Gioco {


    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        PaintRect();

    }

    public static void PaintRect() {

        g.drawRect(100,100,300,300);
        g.drawLine(100,100,100,100);
        g.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println("Trasut");
        credits.setText("Kitebbiv");
        credits.setBackground(null);
        credits.setEditable(false);
        credits.setFocusable(false);
        credits.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        credits.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.add(credits);
        g.getPaint();
    }
```

How can I create a `JFrame` the triangle, square and rectangle? correct my code thanks

Comment: Post less code. Try to draw one figure then somebody can help. This snippet is too long

Comment: *correct my code thanks*, that's a lot of code, Consider going through one problem at a time. Draw the rectangle, once that works, try drawing the square, once done, draw the triangle. If stuck with any, post a [mcve] for that part. But I will indeed correct your code: 1) Don't use `null-layout` instead use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) as Swing was designed to work with different OS, PLAFs, screen sizes and resolutions, and also don't call `setLocation()`, see [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html)...

Comment: ... and the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing). 2) Don't call `frame.setSize()` instead use `pack();` when you use a layout manager, 3) You're creating an instance of `Graphics2D` this isn't how it works, please check the tutorial on [Custom painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). 4) You're over using `static` see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) to know why you shouldn't use it in this case.

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] since it seems you haven't gone through it nor the [help] and also read [ask], once done, come back and [edit] your question in order to add your [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your issue and follows the above recommendations.

Comment: 1) *"sorry for this code"* Please [edit] your question and post your code there, not in comments. 2) Tip, add @efekctive or whoever you want to notify in a comment (The `@` is important)

Comment: Did you read the links I posted above? You just copy-pasted a piece of your above code! (1- for not even making the attempt to make a [mcve])

Comment: now i correct please help me

Comment: [Drawing a triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564837/java-draw-a-triangle/21565087#21565087)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I even start writing my answer I need to encourage you to read carefully to: How to create a valid [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

---

1. From your (now deleted) code, I see you haven't gone through the [Swing Tutorial on Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) yet or you didn't even pay attention to it, this line will cause you problems

   ```
   static Graphics2D g = new Graphics2D()
   ```
2. The excessive use of `static` modifier will harm you, `static` isn't a cross-method magic word to make your variables be accessible anywhere in your program, you should instead create an instance of your program and call the methods from there (they not being static), see [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil), and you should really go back and [learn the essentials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) before adding more complexity to your learning with a GUI and even more with Swing custom painting.
3. You're making use of `setBounds()` method, which suggests (and I can confirm in your deleted code) that you're using a `null-layout`:

   ```
   panel.setLayout(null);
   ```

   You should really consider checking the [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
4. You're making use of a deprecated method [`JFrame#show()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show()) instead you should be using [`JFrame#setVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean)) method.
5. You're manually setting the size of your `JFrame`, you should instead use a layout manager and call the method [`JFrame#pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) which will calculate the preferred size for your `JFrame` or override your component's `getPreferredSize()`.
6. On your deleted code, you had a `MouseListener` attached to a `JButton`, instead you need to use an `ActionListener`, see [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to learn this.
7. You're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which could make your program to freeze, because Swing is not Thread safe. You can correct this by writing your `main` method as follows:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               //Your constructor here
           }
       });
   }
   ```
8. You should be more polite: *"correct my code thanks"* sounds like an order, I would have said that like *could you help me?* which sounds like a request / petition for someone to give you a hand, because they can, not because they must help you, all the above points correct your code.

---

After all the above has being said (and which you should read carefully) we can continue to the coding part:

In order to draw a rectangle we need to learn something about a rectangle:

- A rectangle has a width and a height, both are different
- The way to draw a rectangle in Swing is with <s>[`drawRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))</s> [`draw(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) of the `Graphics2D` method where `Shape` would be an instance of [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html)

To draw a square we need to know that:

- A square has a width and a height, both are equal size
- The way to draw a square in Swing is with <s>[`drawRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))</s> [`draw(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) of the `Graphics2D` method where `Shape` would be an instance of [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html)

You must be saying... *"But the method you're using to draw the square is the same as the rectangle!"*, well... yep, we are, the difference lies in that we're going to pass a `width` and `height` equal size for the square and different size for the rectangle.

To draw a triangle you need to know that:

- A triangle has 3 sides, they can be same or different sizes
- We have no method to `drawTriangle` in Swing, but we have <s>[`drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon(int[],%20int[],%20int))</s> [`draw(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) of the `Graphics2D` method, which will draw a Polygon of `nPoints` (3 in this case), taking the coords from each array element of `xPoints` for the `X` coords and `yPoints` for the `Y` coords and where `Shape` would be an instance of [`Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html)

Now, putting all that together we should have all that code in an overridden method of our `JPanel` called [`paintComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) as shown in the tutorial (See point #1). It should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //ALWAYS call this method first!
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50); //Draws square
    g.drawRect(10, 75, 100, 50); //Draws rectangle
    g.drawPolygon(new int[] {35, 10, 60}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3); //Draws triangle
}
```

But we also need to override another method [`getPreferredSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getPreferredSize()) on our `JPanel`, (see: [Should I avoid the use of setPreferred|Maximum|MinimumSize in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) the general consensus says yes), otherwise our `JFrame` will be smaller than what we want, so it should look like this:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}
```

Don't forget to call `@Override` in those methods!

With only those methods we have completed our program to draw the shapes, but I know that if I don't post the whole code you'll end up writing the above methods in a place that won't work or cause you compilation errors, so the whole code (which in fact is a MCVE or SSCCE (see the very first paragraph in this answer to see what each means)) that produces the below output is:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShapesDrawing {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ShapesDrawing().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g); //ALWAYS call this method first!
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50); //Draws square
                g.drawRect(10, 75, 100, 50); //Draws rectangle
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {35, 10, 60}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3); //Draws triangle
                g.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I really hope you read every link I posted here, because it's worth it

And if you need to fill the shapes then call `fillRect` and `fillPolygon` instead of `drawRect` and `drawPolygon`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //ALWAYS call this method first!
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50); //Draws square
    g.fillRect(150, 10, 50, 50); //Fills a square
    g.drawRect(10, 75, 100, 50); //Draws rectangle
    g.fillRect(150, 70, 100, 50); //Fills a square
    g.drawPolygon(new int[] {35, 10, 60}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3); //Draws triangle
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {185, 150, 215}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3); //Fills triangle
    g.dispose();
}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

As per @MadProgrammer's comment:

> Could we avoid using `draw/fillPolygon` in favor of using the updated Shapes API ... provides much more functionality and is generally easier to use :P

Here's the updated `paintComponent` method using the Shapes API:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //ALWAYS call this method first!

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 50, 50));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 10, 50, 50));

    g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 75, 100, 50));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 75, 100, 50));

    g2d.draw(new Polygon(new int[] {35, 10, 60}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3));
    g2d.fill(new Polygon(new int[] {185, 150, 215}, new int[] {150, 200, 200}, 3));

    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Could we avoid using `draw/fillPolygon` in favor of using the updated Shapes API ... provides much more functionality and is generally easier to use :P

Comment: Frakcool Thank you so much for having me taking the time and making me understand how to create the various geometric shapes

Comment: @MadProgrammer please see edit :) and thanks for the tip, I'll be using the Shapes API from now on :D

Comment: @Sasapp no problem, just be sure to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)